# Julia set fractals

Tags: python, pygame, iteration, complex-numbers, fractals

I wrote a program to generate Julia set fractals. The program also allows the user to enter their value of c or let the program generate a random value. Here is the code :-

```
import pygame, sys, math, cmath, random
from pygame.locals import *
print("Julia set fractal generator")
custom = int(input("Do you want a custom set? Yes(1); No(-1): "))
if custom == -1:
    c = complex((random.randint(-999,1000))/1000.0,(random.randint(-999,1000))/1000.0)
else:
    a = float(input("Real?: "))
    b = float(input("Imaginary?: "))
    c = complex(a,b)
lim = 4
limn = -4
mul = 0
iteration_detail = 100
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512,512),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Julia set fractal generator")
def iterate (px_i,py_i,iters):
    itnum = 1
    z = complex(((px_i-256)/512.0)*4,((py_i-256)/512.0)*4)
    while itnum <= iters:
        if z.real >= lim or z.imag >= lim or z.real <= limn or z.imag <= limn:
                break
        z = z**2 + c
        itnum += 1
return(z.real, z.imag, itnum)
def pixel_color_set (iterx, itery, iterations):
    pixel_color = (0,0,0)
    if iterx >= lim or itery >= lim or iterx <= limn or itery <= limn:
        if iterations < 2:
                pixel_color = (204,0,102)
        elif iterations == 2:
                pixel_color = (204,0,204)
        elif iterations == 3:
                pixel_color = (102,0,204)
        elif iterations ==4:
                pixel_color = (0,0,204)
        elif iterations ==5:
                pixel_color = (0,102,204)
        elif iterations ==6:
                pixel_color = (0,204,204)
        elif iterations ==7:
                pixel_color = (0,204,102)
        elif iterations ==8:
                pixel_color = (0,204,0)
        elif iterations ==9:
                pixel_color = (102,204,0)
return(pixel_color)
def draw_pixel (px, py, color):
return(screen.fill(color, ((px, py),(1, 1))))
while 1:
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                        mul = 0.1
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                        mul = -0.1
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                        pygame.image.save(screen, "fractal.jpg")
        if event.type == KEYUP:
                 if event.key == K_UP:
                        mul = 0
                 elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                        mul = 0
        c += mul
ypxl = 0
while ypxl < 512:
        xpxl = 0
        while xpxl < 512:
                ipxl = iterate(xpxl,ypxl,iteration_detail)
                cpxl = pixel_color_set(ipxl[0], ipxl[1], ipxl[2])
                draw_pixel(xpxl, ypxl, cpxl)
                xpxl += 1
        ypxl += 1
pygame.display.update()
```

The code does work but it doesn't generate fractals as expected. For example this fractal :-
`z = z**2 + c`    Where `c` is equal to
`c = complex(-0.1, 0.651)`
It is supposed to look like this
[image: From Wikipedia]

But it looks like this
[image: Generated by the program]

What is wrong in my code? Also I am unable to make a zooming mechanism... Some help there would be appreciated.

Comment: It probably has to do with the lack of a zooming mechanism.. Fractals are very different depending on where you zoom in.  Check out youtube for videos of zooming fractals.  Looks like you just got a less interesting position.

Comment: @turbo Actually, this is the outermost position of the fractal. If my program were to work properly, The result would have been similar to the image above.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you did too few or too many iterations?

Comment: Try increasing the iterations

Comment: @turbo I have tried 10, 50, 100, 1000, 10000 iterations, all of which give the same result. :-/

Comment: The same result? Exactly? that doesn't sound right..

Comment: @turbo Not exactly... It does add more details to the border though... Here is the image -> [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=nz526q&s=5). The iterations here are 999999

Comment: You're only coloring pixels that terminate before 9 iterations?

Comment: @M4rtini What value should I set it to then? I am very new to the world of fractals... If I put "if iterations > 9", Every pixel escapes according to the program!

Comment: I'm not sure what strategy to use for the coloring. But with only 9 distinct values you won't get much detail. There is some info on the wikipage of the julia set. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set#Distance_estimation

Comment: @M4rtini I get some black spots after I reduce iteration... I guess I have to keep experimenting. Here is the image [click here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29elu8&s=5)

Comment: You could try setting the color values equal to `iterations * int(255.0/ iteration_detail)`

Comment: @M4rtini This looks promising! I will tweak the settings a little more... [image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2s1q3k2&s=5)

Comment: By setting the RGB values equal to what i said in the last comment, and using c = -0.75 + 0.11i i get this: [image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2dujxbk&s=5#.UtavnJ55MXt)

Comment: @M4rtini from my program? Wow! Please tell me how you did that?! Did you put that in each elif statement in the function?

Comment: Added a answer with what i changed.

Comment: @M4rtini I can't thank you enough! Thanks to you I got from that crap to this beauty :- [Image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1z4ljjn&s=5)

Comment: Here is also a great article about a julia set fractals http://kukuruku.co/hub/algorithms/julia-set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing `the pixel_color_set` like this gave good results.
The iterations going from 0 to `iteration_detail` is scaled into the range of 0 to 255.

```
def pixel_color_set (iterx, itery, iterations):
    pixel_color = (0,0,0)
    if iterx >= lim or itery >= lim or iterx <= limn or itery <= limn:
        RGB =int(math.sqrt(iterations) * int(255.0 / math.sqrt(iteration_detail)))
        # RGB = iterations * int(255.0/ iteration_detail)
        pixel_color = (RGB, RGB, RGB)
    return(pixel_color)
```

I think the one with `math.sqrt` looked a bit better, but try both and pick what you want.

Comment: How can I thank you? :) I wish I can do something to repay you. Without your help I wouldn't have been able to do anything... Thanks!!

Comment: No problems, that's what this site is for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use your original coloration algorithm if you use the remainder of division by 10 of the iteration count to decide the color. But then you have to check first for the maximum count to have the inside always black. Or encode the maximum count by setting the iteration number to -1 after the computation loop, this is easier to check in the coloration method.

Comment: I still need to make a method to zoom... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Whats wrong with my code ?

Nothing, you have good image, but you want different image. To make new image change the drawing algorithm.  The image you want to make is : [Julia set for fc(z)=z*z + c and c=-0.1+0.651. Made using DEM/J](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Julia_dem_c%3D-0.1%2B0.651.png)

It is made with [distance estimation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/Julia_set#External_distance_estimation) not with escape time as in your program

So simply change the algorithm

HTH